# Renaming page.tsx files in Nextjs 13 app directory

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I want to be able to rename page.tsx files in nextjs 13 app directory to something like theRouteName.page.tsx or something like this. because if all the pages are named page.tsx it's gonna be a pain to work on multiple pages in the IDE, I know we can write some kind of plugin for VS code etc. but that is not the option for me. any ideas?

Comment: Is a non sense: you have one page.tsx per segment. Look at the folder (segment) your page is, and you have the solution of your problem. Does your IDE show folders or fiile path?

Comment: I agree with OP that when you have a lot of tabs open in VS Code, having many tabs all called page.tsx is not helpful, Would be great if the files could be better named, or a comment added to the file to appear as the name in the tab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend checking out the official Next.js 13 documentation on pageExtensions to personalize page file names

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/pageExtensions

By exploring this section of the documentation, you'll find a practical examples on how to configure page name extensions to align with your preferences

Comment: That's very cool and it resolves the problem 100%, with an angular style syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can name your file whatever you want and put it wherever, and then just have a single line in page.ts or tsx that imports it and exports it as default.

Comment: This is actually a good solution in this situation. But there are a few problems problems though, too many files, and you'll have to change routing in two places each time. gets lost in big projects. I'm still using Pages router and it's working neat. so far I don't see any reason to switch. but thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For VS Code, you can force it to display the parent folder name next to the file name in the tab.

So if you have a file "/customers/page.tsx" it will display "page.tsx customers" in the tab.

To achieve this:

1. File -> Preferences -> Settings
2. Search "workbench.editor.labelFormat"
3. In the dropdown option select "short"

Answer (score 1):

I agree with OP, even with a simple app it cam become confusing:
[image]

Let alone what will happen with an enterprise app.
What I've done is created a default export in the page.tsx, for example:

page.tsx:

```
import Homepage from './home.page'
export default Homepage
```

It's still not perfect, but better than it was before

[image]

You could also do the same for layouts, error, etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is the structure of this framework in nextjs 13 and must be followed
[enter link for more details of pages](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts)